# Django: adding excluded fields after ModelForm submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a ModelForm where I excluded the `selected_season` field. The model looks like this (showing relevant part):

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    selected_season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

before saving the form I have tried adding that field in:

```
if form.is_valid():
   form.save(commit=False)
   form.selected_season = '21'
   form.save()
```

But it shows `null value in column "selected_season_id" violates not-null constraint`
I added the 21 because there are 2 objects in my Season table, '21' and '22'. How do I fix this?

**EDIT**

The Season model looks like this:

```
class Season(models.Model):
    season = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
    running = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The primary key is not an `id`, but the `season` attribute. After I had to modify Pravan's answer:

```
if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            season=Season.objects.get(season=21)
            form.selected_season = season
            form.save()
```

but the problem still remains.

Comment: `'21'` is a string, you need to assign a `Season` object to `form.selected_season`

Comment: Could you tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

get the object and assign like below

```
if form.is_valid():
   form.save(commit=False)
   season=Season.objects.get(season="21")
   form.selected_season = season
   form.save()
```

Comment: I have tried this but had to do it in a different method. The problem is still the same. Please check the edit

Comment: i updated according to your primary key check once.

Answer (score -2):

It is throwing the error because you didn't write `null=True, blank=True` in your models, and Registered users with that form. Adding them should solve the problem.
Try:

```
selected_season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: But I need the values to be present